# cannot resolve dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Im really stuck whit this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.testing"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile project(':External-Module')
}
```

I dont know what to do... I cant build project and use dependencies from External module.

the error is:

```
Error:(7, 47) error: package com.example.android.transfer does not exist
Error:(19, 9) error: cannot find symbol class ClientData
Error:(19, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable ClientData
Error:Execution failed for task ':Testing:compileDebugJava'.
```

but inside the IDE all is well and I can see the module

[image]

Here is also the External Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.externalmodule"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
}
```

Comment: Is "External-Module" a Gradle project? is it defined on the parent settings.gradle? How's you directory tree?

Comment: @RobertEstivill yes its a Gradle project. yes its define in settings.gradle. All files are on the same level

Comment: Is External-Module a java lib? android lib? Does it overwrite the package? Can you post a picture of the whole directory tree ? Thanks

Comment: @RobertEstivill the External-Module is Android module.

Comment: That's not the real directory tree, that's just the Android Studio "Android view" that groups content based on the android apps directory structure. Please add the External-Module gradle build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "External-Module" is an Android library, so according to the [Gradle+Android documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects) instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

it should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

// Old version of the plugin
// apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

Also, make sure the imports in your app matches the package you are overriding in your library build script. Looks like the app is not founding `com.example.android.transfer` but the library package really is `com.example.externalmodule`

Comment: thank you for your effort, Now I can go to sleep :) it works it is the `android-library`